# C : Why the size of my pizza is not 10 bytes?

Tags: c, sizeof

I was learning `sizeof` and this stumbles me. I decided to do this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
    char *myWord="PIZZA";
    printf ("The size of P is...:%d\n",sizeof("P"));
    printf ("The size of I is...:%d\n",sizeof("I"));
    printf ("The size of Z is...:%d\n",sizeof("Z"));
    printf ("The size of A is...:%d\n",sizeof("A"));
    printf ("The size of R is...:%d\n",sizeof("R"));
    printf ("The size of PIZZA is...:%d\n",sizeof("PIZZA"));
    printf ("The size of *PIZZA is..:%d\n",sizeof(myWord));
    return 0;
}
```

And I'm very surprised to see the result:

```
The size of P is...:2
The size of I is...:2
The size of Z is...:2
The size of A is...:2
The size of R is...:2
The size of PIZZA is...:6
The size of *PIZZA is..:4
```

The question are the following:

  *Why*
  the size of array char and pointer char is respectively, 6 bytes and 4 bytes

  *How*
  come they "cruncuh" a 5 letters * 2bytes = 10 bytes. into 6 bytes and 4 bytes?

Let me explain my second question:

From what I know, C doesn't store the letters as *it is*, but store the letter as ASCII code.

This is proofed by this code

`printf ("ASCII CODE of A:%d",myWord[4]);`

results:

`ASCII CODE of A:65`

So assuming I'm right, then C stores the word as `[80,73,90,65,65]`, so  5 chars * 2 bytes is equal..... 10 bytes! But the code above shows 6 bytes and 4 bytes! That's what I mean by *crunch* in the question number two. C crunches 10 bytes into 6 bytes and 4 bytes.

Any enlightenment is appreciated =)

Comment: `myWord` is a pointer, so the size of a pointer (in your case) is 4 bytes. Also, each `char` is only 1 byte. You're seeing 2 bytes for each "character" because they're actually 2-character strings (one character plus one null-terminator).

Comment: `char` is only 1 byte? That explains.

Comment: @Realdeo `char` is defined to always be exactly one byte by the C standard.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition, regardless of how many bits it contains.

Comment: And by POSIX `CHAR_BIT == 8`.

Comment: each part of the pizza costs 2 but when you get the whole pizza you get a discount for only 6 instead of 10. and of course a snapshot * of the pizza is even cheaper, only 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each single letter is a string of 2 characters the letter and the null end of string marker.  "PIZZA" is 5 letters + null for 6 characters and *PIZZA is the size of the variable, a pointer, which is 4 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

`"P"` isn't a `char`, it's a *string literal*.  Strings are null terminated, so require one extra byte of storage.  Hence `sizeof("P")` is 2.  String literals are stored as arrays of type `char`.

Likewise, `"PIZZA"` is six bytes to include the null terminator (`'\0'`).

If you check `sizeof('P')`, you'll get the same as `sizeof(int)`, since `'P'` is a *character literal*, and those are stored as int values, although they are commonly assigned to a `char` since they don't exceed the ASCII range.

`myWord` is a pointer, hence whatever size that is on your system -- evidently 4.

Answer (score 1):

One letter is **not** two bytes. It's one byte. `"P"` is a string, though, and C strings are 0-terminated: they have a trailing 0 byte automatically added by the compiler, hence an `N`-letter string's size is `N + 1`.

As to your second question: `"PIZZA"` is a string literal. It's an **array** of 6 `char`s. Hence its size is 6.

`char *myWord`, on the other hand, declares `myWord` to be a **pointer.** Apparently, the size of a pointer on your platform is 4. The fact that you can "assign an array to a pointer", i. e. that there's an implicit conversion from `T []` to `T *` in C is just a(n often misunderstood) feature of C.

Answer (score 0):

"Why the size of array char and pointer char is respectively, 6 bytes and 4 bytes "

The array has 6 elements - 5 characters and zero terminator. Each element is a character which is one byte.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess but I think in case of each of these string there is a end string char added to each case so when you do a sizeof("P") you are actually seeing  sizeof('P' + '\0')

Answer (score 0):

```
sizeof("P");//size is 2 because each char takes 1 byte and 
//it is  trailed by '\0' so two Bytes
```

*if you try `sizeof(char);` it would give you 1 Byte*

*if you try `sizeof(int);` it would give you 2 Bytes*

But here `sizeof("P")` will be 2 bytes because it is trailed by '\0' which takes one more Byte.Same apply for `sizeof("Pizza"); // 5+ trailing \0 = 6 bytes`

---

`sizeof(myWord);` is 4 Bytes since it is a pointer

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from here:

```
char *myWord="PIZZA";
```

`"PIZZA"` is a *string literal*; it is stored as a 6-element array of `char` (5 letters plus 0 terminator) in such a way that it's available over the lifetime of the program.  `myWord` is a variable of type `char *`, and it's initialized with the *address* of the first letter in the string.  In memory, it would look something like this (this is how it plays out on my system, anway):

```
Item        Address          0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03
----        -------          ---- ---- ---- ----
"PIZZA"     0x4006e0          'P'  'I'  'Z'  'Z'
            0x4006e4          'A'   0    ??   ??
              ...
 myWord     0x7fffa7e983d0   0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
            0x7fffa7e983d4   0x00 0x40 0x06 0x90
```

`sizeof("PIZZA")` (or `sizeof "PIZZA"`; the parentheses are only required when the operand is a type name) gives you the total number of bytes in the array (in this case, 6).

`sizeof(myWord)` (or `sizeof myWord`; again, the parentheses aren't needed in this case) gives you the size of the *pointer variable* in bytes; in your case, 4.

`sizeof("P")` is giving you the size of the *string literal* `"P"`, which is 2 (one letter plus the 0 terminator).  If you want the size of the *character constant* `'P'`, you would write `sizeof 'P'` (note single quotes instead of double quotes).  Except...

In C, the type of a character constant like `'P'` is `int`, not `char`, so the result (most likely) still won't be 1.

Here's how things play out on my system:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
  char c = 'P';
  char *myWord = "PIZZA";

  printf( "sizeof \"PIZZA\"    == %zu\n", sizeof "PIZZA" );
  printf( "sizeof myWord     == %zu\n", sizeof myWord );
  printf( "value of myWord   == %p\n", (void *) myWord );
  printf( "sizeof *myWord    == %zu\n", sizeof *myWord );
  printf( "value of *myWord  == %c\n", *myWord );
  printf( "address of myWord == %p\n", (void *) &myWord );
  printf( "sizeof \"P\"        == %zu\n", sizeof "P" );
  printf( "sizeof 'P'        == %zu\n", sizeof 'P' );
  printf( "sizeof c          == %zu\n", sizeof c );

  return 0;
}

[fbgo448@n9dvap997]~/prototypes/sizes: gcc -o sizes -g -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror -Wa,-aldh=sizes.lst sizes.c
[fbgo448@n9dvap997]~/prototypes/sizes: ./sizes
sizeof "PIZZA"    == 6
sizeof myWord     == 8
value of myWord   == 0x4006e0
sizeof *myWord    == 1
value of *myWord  == P
myWord string     == PIZZA
address of myWord == 0x7fffd8a9eb40
sizeof "P"        == 2
sizeof 'P'        == 4
sizeof c          == 1
value of c        == P
```